# Cannot find symbol: Circle Error

Tags: java

I have written the following code and keep getting the error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
        Circle first = new Circle();    
        ^
  symbol:   class Circle
  location: class TestCircle
error: cannot find symbol
        Circle first = new Circle();     
                           ^
  symbol:   class Circle
  location: class TestCircle
```

This is repeated for the second and third as well. Here are the codes:

```
public class TestCircle {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // Create three Circle objects
    Circle first = new Circle();     
    Circle second = new Circle();
    Circle third = new Circle();

    // Initialize radius for first and second circles
    first.setRadius(6.0);
    second.setRadius(15.0);

    // Display circle Info
    first.displayCircle();
    second.displayCircle();
    third.displayCircle();      
}

}

public class Circle {

// 
private double radius;    // circle radius
private double diameter;  // circle diameter
private double area;      // circle area
private final double pi = 3.14159265358979;   // value of pi

Circle()      // Constructor
{
    radius = 1;
    diameter = 2 * radius;
    area = pi * radius * radius;        
}

void setRadius(double rad)   // method to set radius and calculate the other two values
{
    radius = rad;
    diameter = 2 * radius;
    area = pi * radius * radius;
}

double getRadius()    // method to get radius
{
    return radius;
}

void displayCircle()     // method to display circle parameters
{
    System.out.println("Circle Info");
    System.out.println("Radius: " + radius);
    System.out.println("Diameter: " + diameter);
    System.out.println("Area: " + area);
}

}
```

Any help in solving this is appreciated.

Comment: Your Circle constructor is package private.  Add the access public if you mean it to be a public constructor.

Comment: Are you really getting _two_ errors on each of the three lines (i.e. 6 total errors about `Circle`)?  If that's the case, then everybody's answer about adding `public` to the constructor doesn't answer the question by itself.  If `Circle` is in a different package, you may need to `import` it in `TestCircle` (_and_ add `public` to the constructor).

Comment: yes a total of 6 errors

Comment: Small thing, Java has a predefined pi-value. You could use `Math.PI` to remove the need of declaring it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your constructor public.
If you don't make it public, then it can only be accessed within the package which is the reason for your error.

Answer (score 0):

It's not mandatory to add public before the package. But for a best practice you should make each class in a separate file. And it will work. Try this:

**Circle class :**

```
public class Circle {

    private double radius;    // circle radius
    private double diameter;  // circle diameter
    private double area;      // circle area
    private final double pi = 3.14159265358979;   // value of pi

    public Circle() {   // Constructor
        radius = 1;
        diameter = 2 * radius;
        area = pi * radius * radius;
    }

    void setRadius(double rad) // method to set radius and calculate the other two values
    {
        radius = rad;
        diameter = 2 * radius;
        area = pi * radius * radius;
    }

    double getRadius() // method to get radius
    {
        return radius;
    }

    void displayCircle() // method to display circle parameters
    {
        System.out.println("Circle Info");
        System.out.println("Radius: " + radius);
        System.out.println("Diameter: " + diameter);
        System.out.println("Area: " + area);
    }

}
```

**TestCircle class:**

```
public class TestCircle {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Create three Circle objects
        Circle first = new Circle();
        Circle second = new Circle();
        Circle third = new Circle();

        // Initialize radius for first and second circles
        first.setRadius(6.0);
        second.setRadius(15.0);

        // Display circle Info
        first.displayCircle();
        second.displayCircle();
        third.displayCircle();
    }

}
```

**Notice**

If you want to use a single file don't forget to remove the word public before `class Circle`. Because each class which declared as public should be in a new separate file.

Comment: I added the above { } and still recevied the same errors. I am not sure how else to make it public.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `Circle` is probably in a different package than `TestCircle`.  If that's the case (if `Circle.java` has `package abcde;` or something at the top), then `TestCircle` will need to import it:

```
import abcde.Circle;
```

And, the constructor and *all* the methods in `Circle` have to be made `public`, since the default access ("package-private") doesn't work for a class that's in a different package.

If `Circle` doesn't have a `package` statement, then things should work if `TestCircle.java` and `Circle.java` are in the same directory.  If they're in different directories, but they don't have `package` statements, then I think you will need to set the `CLASSPATH` so that it can refer to all the directories where classes exist, or if you're using an IDE, configure it to find things in a different directory.  But I'd recommend either using packages or putting things in the same directory.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the assistance but I am just not having any luck. I am going to scrap it and try again.